# Check whether the string in truncated in label

Tags: ios, swift

I've created below code in order to change text on whether the text is truncated. however it does not seem to work at all. How can i check whether the text is truncated and then change the string if it is?

```
    //Check text sizes

    let awaySize: CGSize = (match?.awayName?.uppercaseString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(30)]))!
    let homeSize: CGSize = (match?.awayName?.uppercaseString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(30)]))!



    if awaySize.width > awayTeam.frame.size.width {
        awayTeam.text = match?.awayAcro?.uppercaseString
    } else {
        awayTeam.text = match?.awayName?.uppercaseString
    }

    if homeSize.width > homeTeam.frame.size.width {
        homeTeam.text = match?.homeAcro?.uppercaseString
    } else {
        homeTeam.text = match?.homeName?.uppercaseString
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done this way:

```
let labelSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 20)
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: labelSize))
label.text = "Hello world"

let nsText = NSString(string: label.text ?? "")
let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: label.font]
let textSize = nsText.sizeWithAttributes(textAttributes)

if label.frame.width >= textSize.width {
    print("Text will fit")
} else {
    print("Text won't fit")
}
```

Comment: why is `sizeWithAttributes` nil?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that one. Fixed in the sample.